# Removing Duplicate Values from a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript to get values and assign to variable "UserIds". But I want to remove any duplicates `

```
javascript:
(
function()
{ 
var n=escape("\r\n");
var UserIds = $('tr.background-light:contains(".")').map
(function() {return $.text([this]);  }).get().join(n); alert(UserIds);
}
)();
```

The above code finds the answer twice from the IE DOM explorer. Thus the result will be something like:

1. GRON, NYA
2. PER, RALLE
3. POIR, PGE
4. RICD, CLEEN
5. GRON, NYA
6. PER, RALLE
7. POIR, PGE
8. RICD, CLEEN

I only wanted to get the 1st 4 for on this particular occurrence.

Comment: javascript and java are two different langauges

Comment: oops my bad. It has already been removed by you , I guess..

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter an array with [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)

```js
let UserIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

let filteredUserIds = UserIds.filter((id, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(id) === index)

console.log(filteredUserIds)
```

Comment: I am not sure the var "UserIds" is an array. "UserIds" gets the value and using the escape function to organize it one after the other.    n=escape("\r\n"); var UserIds = $('tr.background-light:contains(".")').map
(function() {return $.text([this]);  }).get().join(n);. Anyhow, I tried including your code as it is, but no result has been given.